# On consuming composites

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Given this abstract class:

```
public abstract class File
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void Add(File newFile);
}
```

The basis of a composite can be generated:

```
    public class LogFile : File
    {
        private string _name;

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public override void Add(File newFile)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class LogFiles : File
    {
        private IList<File> _files = new List<File>();

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override void Add(File newFile)
        {
            _files.Add(newFile);
        }
    }
```

Out of the box, exception code is generated. Most of the time when writing the initial code, this handy. When switching between the collection class and the object class (which is primarily what I deal with) you can easily forget which sort of object you're dealing with. Especially as variables are typically named using the abstract class name:

```
    File thisFile = new LogFile {Name = "Monday.log"};

    File thatFile = new LogFiles();
    thatFile.Add(new LogFile() { Name = "Tuesday.log" });
    thatFile.Add(new LogFile() { Name = "Wednesday.log" });
    thatFile.Name = "My files"; // Runtime error
```

However, if this code is left in, when these objects are consumed upstream (as bona fide composites), there can be issues when the parametersless constructor is used and an unimplemented property throws an exception. A common example being various forms of serialisation:

```
static void SerializeThis(File fileSet)
{
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(fileSet);                  
}
```

In this case, the code can simply be refactored to remove the exceptions:

```
    public class LogFile : File
    {
        private string _name;

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public override void Add(File newFile)
        {            
        }
    }

    public class LogFiles : File
    {
        private IList<File> _files = new List<File>();

        public override string Name 
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            set
            {   

            }
        }

        public override void Add(File newFile)
        {
            _files.Add(newFile);
        }
    }
```

But this removes the safeguards for derived classes and leaves the code looking somewhat crufty. There seems to me to be a dichotomy between the raison d'être of a composite: "I shouldn't care whether I am an object or a collection of objects" and making sure each derived class is used correctly (as a derived class).

I can't help but think I am missing something fundamental here - any thoughts?

**EDIT**

As an aside, some coding tools such as ReSharper implement auto-properties rather than getters and setters containing exceptions. While this isn't completely foolproof, it is certainly a better approach.

Comment: Not an answer, so I won't post it as such, but having methods that throw `NotImplementedException` screams red flag to me.  It's a direct violation of Liskov Subsitution Principle.  It's okay to have a collection of files that can contain 1 or even 0 files, but I would be very careful to treat a *collection* of files like a single file.

Comment: Yes, at the heart of the problem is the absence of the rules as to *how* the composite is consumed. Name could equally be valid for a set of files as for a file itself. This all leads to the question: which is object and which is collection for which there isn't always a clear cut answer.

Comment: You **don't have a composite**. You have a type and a collection of that type, and you are forcing that into a base class, and seeing that there are problems. Start with what the consumer *can consume*, and see what *implementations* there can be. You might end up with a composite, or you **might not**

Comment: Can you state a contract for the `File` base class?  Is there some kind of behavior that implementors of that class should provide?  If the `Add` method is part of the base class I would expect all sub-classes to provide some consistent behavior.

Comment: @Caleth That is certainly an aspect of it. I only tend to deal with the derived classes and seldom have anything to do with the composites themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nub of the problem seems to be lack of clarity in *how* the composite is consumed in every case. As it currently stands, the object and the collection class have clearly defined roles but are composites in name (i.e. their definition) only. As such, this requires some of the heavy lifting to be done by the consumer.

The waters would be muddied further by referring to object and collection by class name. More subtle behaviour should be used to determine object and collection classes.

A better approach would be to define some kind of default behaviour that would service all 3 uses: object, collection and agnostic.

One possible way is to make the methods and properties in the base class virtual. This avoids the thorny problem of code having to be written for methods and properties in derived classes that will never be used (I've added the AllFiles getter for completeness):

```
    public class File
    {
        protected string _name = string.Empty;
        protected IList<File> _allFiles = new List<File>();

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual void Add(File newFile)
        {
            _allFiles.Add(newFile);
        }

        public virtual IList<File> AllFiles
        {
            get
            {
                return _allFiles;
            }
        }
    }
```

This has a number of benefits:

Firstly, the derived classes are cleaner because they only contain the required overrides.

Secondly, it forces the developer to consider the composite holistically up front rather than being the sum of its parts. This is particularly important where the composite is consumed in other layers the developer may have little control of.

Thirdly, it simply removes the guesswork as to what to put in methods the consumer isn't interested in - a persistent problem in the canonical abstract class solution touted pretty much everywhere. This, ultimately, is what never sat right with me from the very first time I used the pattern.

Comment: You still mix concepts. A consumer of the class MUST NOT need to know anything about its implementation. `AddFile` is only useful with some list, it won't work with a "normal" implementation. But such a method can be added to an interface derived from the base interface, and a consumer may require that derived interface instead of the base interface. But then, the idea behind the composite pattern has been lost. On the other hand, the adding of further base instance to the list might be done by some dependency injection framework at the time of construction of the composite -

Comment: ... then the interface need not contain methods for adding/removing the base instances it contains.

Answer (score 6):

Your design is flawed.

Your example violates the [Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) because the contract (the abstract class `File`) implicitly states that you can get and set a name (`string Name { get; set; }`) and that you can add a new file (`void Add(File newFile)`). Yet class `LogFiles` does not allow to get and set names and class `LogFile` does not allow to add a new file. They do not implement the contract that they state they are implementing (`: File`). `File` mixes a single object semantics with a collection semantics; however, an implementation can either provide the one or the other but not both. You should think about splitting the `File` class into two distinct interfaces instead of using the composite pattern (see [Interface segregation principle ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)). A concrete class would implement either the one or the other. This also tells the consumer how he can use an object.

```
var fileObject = GetFileObject();
// Using the new C# 7.0 pattern matching
switch (fileObject)
{
    case ISingleFile singleFile:
        singleFile.Name = file1;
        break;
    case IMultiFile multiFile:
        multiFile.Add(file1);
        multiFile.Add(file2);
        multiFile.Add(file3);
        break;
}
```

The contract is more than a signature, it is also an implicit or explicit statement of what you are supposed to be able to do. The implementing/deriving classes can widen the set of possibilities, but they are not allowed to narrow them.

In the [Composite design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) you have a component (interface or abstract class) defining operation(s) suited for leaves and composites, where both derive from the component. The composite contains a collection of components.

```
public interface IComponent
{
    void Operation();
    ... possibly more operations here but NO collection specific operation like Add()
}

public class Leaf : IComponent
{
    public void Operation() { <implementation> }
}

public class Composite : IComponent
{
    private ICollection<IComponent> _collection = new ...;

    public void Operation()
    {
        foreach (IComponent c in _collection) c.Operation();
    }
    public void Add(IComponent c) { _collection.Add(c); }
    public void Remove ( ..., GetChild(... etc.
}
```

The operations of the component must be designed to work with leaves and composites as well. Only the composite has operations related to a collection of components.

---

As a concrete (and more realistic) example your example could be rewritten like this

```
// The component
public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(string text);
}

// A Leaf
public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly string _fileName;

    public FileLogger(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(_fileName, text + "\r\n");
    }
}

// Another Leaf type
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Write(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}

// The composite
public class CompositeLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly List<ILogger> _loggers = new List<ILogger>();

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        foreach (var logger in _loggers) {
            logger.Write(text);
        }
    }

    public void Add(ILogger logger)
    {
        _loggers.Add(logger);
    }

    // Not required here: Remove, GetChild, etc.
}
```

Of course, the leaves can have additional members specific to their implementation; however, these specialized members must not be part of the component (base class or interface), otherwise they would violate the [Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In this concrete example, a `FileLogger` could expose the file name as property and the `ConsoleLogger` a text color for the console output. Why not. But to include such properties in the `ILogger` interface would be a violation of LSP as these would not make sense for other logger types including composite loggers. This is where your design is flawed.

Note that you can add loggers and composite loggers to a `CompositeLogger` and thus create a whole tree or hierarchy of components. This is the point of the composite design pattern.

You would use these loggers through [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I.e. you would inject a `ILogger` (e.g. by constructor injection) into your software components to perform some logging. The point is that these components do not know (and don't need to know) which kind of logger they are using. You could inject a file logger, later replace it by a console logger and even later decide to log to both file and console by injection a composite logger without having to make any change to any of your components.

---

Let's consume this composite. As an example we create a calculator

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator // Interface not shown here
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Calculator (ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public double Result { get; set; }

    public void Add(double value)
    {
        _logger.Write($"Result before adding {value}: {Result}");
        Result += value;
        _logger.Write($"Result after adding {value}: {Result}");
    }

    public void Subtract(double value)
    {
        _logger.Write($"Result before subtracting {value}: {Result}");
        Result -= value;
        _logger.Write($"Result after subtracting {value}: {Result}");
    }
}
```

Now let's instantiate and use composites and calculators:

```
ILogger fileLogger1 = new FileLogger(myLogFile);
ILogger fileLogger2 = new FileLogger(anotherLogFile);
ILogger consoleLogger = new ConsoleLogger();

ICalculator consoleLoggingCalculator = new Calculator(consoleLogger);
consoleLoggingCalculator.Add(100);
consoleLoggingCalculator.Subtract(17);

var allfilesLogger = new CompositeLogger();
allfilesLogger.Add(fileLogger1);
allfilesLogger.Add(fileLogger2);
ICalculator filesLoggingCalculator = new Calculator(allfilesLogger);
filesLoggingCalculator.Add(100);
filesLoggingCalculator.Subtract(17);

var allLoggers = new CompositeLogger();
allLoggers.Add(consoleLogger);
allLoggers.Add(allfilesLogger);
ICalculator logToAllCalculator = new Calculator(allLoggers);
logToAllCalculator.Add(100);
logToAllCalculator.Subtract(17);
```

No problem in consumption, no exceptions!

Note that you cannot do this (corresponds to your example `thatFile.Name = "My files"; // Runtime error`):

```
consoleLogger.Add(fileLogger1); // COMPILER ERROR!
```

Comment: Thanks - but you've missed the point somewhat. This isn't about writing composites. It is to do with their consumption.

Comment: No, you are not able to consume your composite because it is badly designed. If the composite was designed right, without violating LSP, then its consumption would be no problem at all. `LogFiles` is not a file, yet it derives from `File`. This makes it impossible to implement and consume it the right way.

Comment: And yet it is implemented and consumed in many other examples I could have used. LSP is moot since it is unclear *where* the contract is defined. Same applies to virtual methods. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963811/liskov-substitution-principle-preconditions-and-abstract-methods).

Comment: What do you mean "LSP is moot since it is unclear _where_ the contract is defined"? You wrote the abstract class and designed the system to use it in a certain way, so you _have_ conceptually defined a contract, and then you've created derived classes that break it.

Comment: I added an example of consumption.

Comment: The principle reads (from Wikipedia): *if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S*. You can't **have** objects of type T since they're abstract - or so the argument goes. Virtual methods are slightly different.

Comment: Who says that. `T` needs not be abstract. Or `T` could be abstract and you can substitute a `S` for a variable of type `T` like in: `T t = new S();`

Comment: Google LSP and virtual/abstract. See [here specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40964192/1371040) from my earlier comment.

Comment: @RobbieDee just because the language forbids objects whose most derived type is `T`, does not mean that LSP does not apply to the subtypes of `T`

Comment: @Caleth I didn't say I agreed with it - just that the discussion is being had (and by far bigger names in the C# world than I).

Comment: @RobbieDee That seems to be arguing: "If there is no code enforcing a precondition / postcondition, it must not exist" which implies that *consumers* of an abstract type can make exactly *zero* assumptions about it's behaviour. If that is the case, then you have a *pointless* type.

Comment: It boils down to *what* determines the contract - discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40964332/1371040). LSP itself in an abstract [sic] concept. It has nothing to say about C# (or any other language) specifically. SOLID itself deals with design **goals**. There is no automated test that can run to prove code is SOLID compliant - although developers can (and do) often agree on what is and isn't.

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner to your answer. LSP aside, I don't wish to reinvent the wheel with regards to the composites I've written and go the interface route. Yes, these have advantages (like DI) but I'm of the view there was a fundamental problem with my approach which I wanted to address rather than starting fresh. The code I outlined was there merely to illustrate the problem rather than a current pressing concern. As I've detailed elsewhere, my exposure to consuming composites is somewhat limited compared to writing them bizarrely...

Comment: ...The derived classes are also used as objects in their own right (albeit referenced via their abstract class). In retrospect, this multi-faceted approach very probably means that the abstract route (maybe even the composite itself) was not a good fit here - something to take into the next design. Thanks for your time on this and to Neil & Caleth +1

Comment: LSP is broken--but the OP mentions this is just code posted for the sake of the question. Actual implementation will not be as such.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Code posted not reflecting the real code is completely useless and misleading.